# Popup message as partial view inside cshtml blazor page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

At profile pages quite often is used partial view. requested from other pages looks like that:

```
<partial name="_StatusMessage" model="Model.StatusMessage" />
```

partial is implmeented that way

```
@model string

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
{
    var statusMessageClass = Model.StartsWith("Error") ? "danger" : "success";
    <div class="alert alert-@statusMessageClass alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        @Model
    </div>
}
```

I would like some messages present as popup windows so i creatred new partial view: _PopUpMessage.cshtml

```
@model string

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
{
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@Model</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work as i was expected. Code is almost the same as in that example.. so it should be correct:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I recommend you modify your question as follows: mention what the problem is - it does not work in what way? Nothing on the screen? Then simplify the example to the point the component only contains a simple span. If that works, then the problem may be in CSS. What browser messages do you see in the console - include them.

Comment: @aleksander_si you was right! problem was because of the CSS. I added 
.modal {
    display: block !important;
} and popup works almost correctly. but now I have another problem.  Popup close button dosn't work! and there is no way to close that window.

Comment: In that case check if you have all the needed javascripts. Some css frameworks rely in them.